# How to set MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU for an Azure Web Site?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Web Site configured for Basic mode (1 dedicated VM with 1 core + 1.75 GB) of RAM.  When I run load testing against it with 25 concurrent users, it falls over.  There are no database calls on the VM, so I believe the problem is MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU and other aspnet.config settings.

So my question is: How do you set **MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU** and other settings like this from aspnet.config for an **Azure Website**?  I can't find any information online about this.

Thanks!

Comment: did you run a profiler to find out what is the issue? Troy Hunt recently run load-testing and his web-site happily serverd 200 requests per second http://www.troyhunt.com/2014/07/scaling-standard-azure-website-to-380k.html

Comment: Not yet, but right now it is dying on 15 requests per second, and I think it has to do with thread pool size.  So trying to figure out how to change machine.config, aspnet.config, etc. in an Azure Website.

Comment: What I'm saying that Azure Web-Sites can handle a lot more out of the box without tinkering with machine.config. I suggest you run a profiler to find out the problem. Unlikely it is thread pool size issue.

Comment: I ran the same code on a local VM with 1 core and 2 GB of RAM (equivalent hardware), with modified machine.config and aspnet.config and the performance is an order of magnitude better, so it is definitely a config issue with Azure websites.  For requests that spend 100 ms+ processing time, I don't see how you could get decent performance without changing the settings.

Comment: @jbro91837 Have you found the cause or a solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating aspnet.config on Azure Web Role](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918032/updating-aspnet-config-on-azure-web-role)

Comment: @jbro91837 I'm encountering the same issue, did you find how to fix it?