# How to modify iis appconfig.config xml file using appcmd?

Tags: iis, appcmd

I have a file called `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config` and I want to add the following params.

```
<applicationPool maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU="10" 
                 maxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU="10"
                 requestQueueLimit="10" />
```

I do not have sites configured and I would like to modify the global `aspnet.config` file only. I tried these commands but neither modified the xml and no way of verifying if the changes took affect.

```
$ appcmd set config /section:processModel /requestQueueLimit:250000 /commit:MACHINE
Applied configuration changes to section "system.web/processModel" for "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST" at configuration commit path "MACHINE"
$ appcmd set config /section:system.webserver/serverRuntime /appConcurrentRequestLimit:100000
Applied configuration changes to section "system.webServer/serverRuntime" for "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST" at configuration commit path "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST"
```

Questions:

1. How do I do this using just appcmd? Is it even possible without a defined site?
2. If I use a registry change, does that override the `aspnet.config` xml file?
3. Can all 3 params be modified exclusively by the registry change?
4. After the changes have been made, what is the best way to test if the parameters took affect?

References:

- [Modify the Request Queue Limit](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2011/11/14/modify-the-request-queue-limit-requestqueuelimit-or-queue-length-in-iis-7/)
- [Registry change for maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27942027)
- [Setting an aspnet.config File per Application Pool](https://blogs.iis.net/owscott/setting-an-aspnet-config-file-per-application-pool)

Comment: Your title asks about `appconfig.config` (I presume you mean `applicationHost.config`?)  but in the body of your question you mention `aspnet.config`. Could you clarify which it is, thanks.

Comment: `appcmd` is designed to manipulate IIS configuration system, which only covers a very small portion of ASP.NET configuration. So don't expect `appcmd` can help on all cases.

Comment: @Kev in the second link it looks like `appcmd` is able to change some values in the XML but the user says they did it with a registry change instead. To clarify, I did mean `aspnet.config`.

Comment: @LexLi yes I agree but not sure if it covers my use cases and if not, do the registry changes reflect what I want without having to modify the xml file directly.